# how to replace part of part of string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two GUIDs. I am looking for to replace `c013d94e` from 1st guid with `cd11d94e` of second guid in `Javascipt`.

I checked javascript `replace()` method but not sure how i can use it with my specific case.

`c013d94e-3210-e511-82ec-303a64efb676` - **1st Guid**

`cd11d94e-3210-e511-82ec-303a64efb676` - **2nd Guid**

Following is my code where i am trying to do it

```
for(var i=0; i < response[1].length;i++)
    angular.forEach($scope.studentPermissions[i][0].Children, function (subject) {
    string 1stGuid= response[1].data[i].Id;   // it contains cd11d94e-3210-e511-82ec-303a64efb676
    subject.Id = // it contains c013d94e-3210-e511-82ec-303a64efb676

    });
```

Comment: Will the other part of the string always be the same, despite the input?  Then you don't even need to use `replace`, you could just construct a new string.

Comment: @Jamen. Yes the other part of 1st string will always be same. How can i use concatenate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Jamen. Yes the other part of 1st string will always be same. How can i use concatenate?

You don't even need to use replace then?  Just make a brand new string:

```
var guid = "cd11d94e-3210-e511-82ec-303a64efb676";
```

---

But, to actually answer the question in the title:

```
var input = "c013d94e-3210-e511-82ec-303a64efb676";
var output = input.replace("c013d94e", "cd11d94e");

console.log(output); // cd11d94e-3210-e511-82ec-303a64efb676
```

But like I said, in your situation this shouldn't be necessary, based on the quote.

Comment: var output = input.replace("c013d94e", "cd11d94e"); This probably wont work becuase my 2nd guid is storied in array. so im iterating from array and getting this length and need to replace string for all child elements.

Answer (score 1):

`replace` takes 2 parameters, the first is the string to search for and the second is the replacement string.  It doesn't modify the original string, it simply returns a new string with the value replaced.

You can perform your replace like this:

```
var guid = 'c013d94e-3210-e511-82ec-303a64efb676';
guid = guid.replace('c013d94e', 'cd11d94e');

console.log(guid); // 'cd11d94e-3210-e511-82ec-303a64efb676'
```